# Chrome pinch zooming bug - the element changes its position after zooming

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

Hi I've got an issue on my site, when the footer is on the position absolute, and the content is smaller that it can't just push the footer normally in the end so I've used some techniques to do that, although I don't know whether it's fine.

The site is [here](https://reportsquestionsznaczki65.000webhostapp.com/footertest)

The problem is seen only on chrome mobile version when pinch zooming on the footer object, [this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dVgI8qSmWb9X84DaUwCz2UJXoyo9ukxA/view?usp=sharing) shows the problem.

Code:

HTML5 & CSS3 with BOOTSTRAP 4.2.1:

https://pastebin.com/q01VHqiN

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: dimgray;
        }
        img[alt="www.000webhost.com"] {
            display:none;
        div.row [class*="col-12"] {
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }
        div.nomarginbottom {
            margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        }
        .display-5 {
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.2;
        }
        /*footer on the bottom */
        html {
            height:100%;
        }
        body {
            min-height:100%;
            position:relative;
        }
        body::after {
            content:'';
            display:block;
            height:100px;
        }
        .footer-bottom {
            position:absolute;
            bottom:0;
            width:100%;
        }

        /* smaller letters on smaller screen - footer */
        @media (max-width: 741px) {
            .footer {
                font-size: 100%;
            }
        }
        @media (max-width: 600px) {
            .footer {
                font-size: 80%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="pt-0 box jumbotron jumbotron-fluid text-center">    
        <h1 class="display-3">Test</h1>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid text-center text-white">

        <div class="row text-center mb-4 d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Web developer in 2019 &lt;b&gt;like&lt;/b&gt;...</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row text-center mb-5">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>Happy New CODE!</h2>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row footer-bottom mt-5">
            <div class="col-12 footer bg-dark p-3 lead mb-0">The site was created by Jan Kustra, the executive of: XeDA+ Department of Websites.</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `left: 0; right: 0;` or `overflow-x: hidden;` for footer div and fill your page with content, this may help.
But you better use `<footer>` tag.

Comment: But my goal is to left the footer always on the bottom no matter of the content whether there's more content or no content at all...

Comment: @znaczki654 you can use position: fixed then but usually footer is always at the bottom but relating on content

Comment: Yeah, but then if there's more content then the footer will cover it, I don't want that. By saying at the bottom I mean that what it's looking like but without that chrome bug... Other web browsers doesn't have that...

Comment: @znaczki654 I suggest positioning all content including footer to relative and it won’t cover it if you set width and height for each of them

Comment: I've tested it and all that happened was that the footer went up what I didn't want.

Comment: I've seen it, thank you for it, but even though it's not what I'd like to have because when you decrease the content it becomes relative but it'll be connected to the sibling apart from being on the bottom. I'd like to make a footer like Google does on their google.com site, they don't pay attention whether the site is filled with content or not

Comment: But they block scaling by putting maximum-scale=1, don't know whether it can be omitted. How to make Google Chrome not to destroy the footer when it's scaling.

Comment: I can write "content="maximum-scale=1" but then scaling will be disabled...

Comment: This bug only happens on chrome mobile browser

Comment: @znaczki654 but wait, it doesn’t destroy footer, it moves it deeper down. Try reinstalling your chrome

Comment: No, it makes some kind of spacing below the footer, just look at the video.

Comment: You can test it on your mobile device on Chrome, I've reinstalled it, but still it doesn't work.